# click event is not working. For few elements it is for few its not

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

In my code for cmd and normal its working, but for #aboutme its not. Don't know why such event is getting ignored while its working for the above snippet.

```
var normal = $(".normal");
var cmd = $(".cmd");
normal.on("click", function(){
  $(".UI").show();

  $(".console").hide();
});
cmd.on("click", function(){
  $(".console").show();
  
  $(".UI").hide();
});


$("#aboutme").on("click",function(){
console.log("okay");
});
```

My Html Code: class dashboard acts as a wrapper.

```
<div class="dashboard ">
            <div class="option">
                <div class="normal">Normal</div>
                <div class="cmd">Terminal</div>
            </div>   
            <hr style="background-color: white;">
            
                <div class="console">
                    </div>
                        
                <div class="UI ">
                    <div class="showcase">
                            <div id="aboutme">
                            <h2><span>&raquo;About</span></h2>
                            <p>Self-motivated fresher seeking a career in recognized organization to prove my skills and utilize my knowledge and intelligence in the growth of organization.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="Skills">
                            <h2><span>Skills</span></h2>
                            <p> <kbd>Programming Languages</kbd>         :    Python, Node.js, C++</p>
                               <p> <kbd>Platform & Development Tools</kbd>   :    VS Code , Spyder and Jupiter Notebook</p> 
                           
                           
                          
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Write full snippet so we can see result.

Comment: without html code it's hard to tell what's going wrong... please provide all the code needed to reproduce the issue

Comment: Please share you HTML page.Is there any element with id aboutme. You are picking two elements by class name and about me by id,  please check it...

Comment: i had updated with HTML code

Comment: Is it possible, that the HTML is added dynamically _after_ the Javascript ran? Can you try, if `$(document).on('click', '#aboutme', function() { ... });` works?

Comment: I only want to select like pressing aboutme button will show the content in aboutme id and pressing skills will show only my skills.

Comment: nothing happened on this $(document).on('click', '#aboutme', function() { ... });  @Boldewyn

Comment: do you see any error in console ?

Comment: NO @SandeepModak All fine in console.

Comment: Thanks for your interest.I solved the issue by my own, I was calling wrong class that's all. Thank you all for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work, can you provide your full HTML

```js
$("#aboutme").on("click",function(){
console.log("okay");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="aboutme">Test</button>
```

Comment: i had posted html code too,please do check that also.